# Mysql insert statement through unix shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

```
filenname="/home/sxxxx/lob.oaxxx"
while read a b 
do
    mdate=$(date -d "$b" +'%s')
    system_todate=$(date +'%s')
    ((diff=$system_todate-$mdate))
    days=`echo "$diff/86400" | bc`
    echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) $a $b $days"
$mysql -e "insert into dataStagDatabase.dataStagTable (as_on_date, hdfs_location, last_modified, no_of_days) values (STR_TO_DATE('$(date +%Y-%m-%d)','%Y-%m-%d'), '$a', STR_TO_DATE('$b', '%Y-%m-%d' )", '$days');" -u root  
done < "$filenname"
```

---

I get the following error, I tried modifying insert statements in various ways, but couldn't succeed.
Kindly help

```
oaisys_datastag.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
oaisys_datastag.sh: line 19: `mysql -e "insert into dataStagDatabase.dataStagTable (as_on_date, hdfs_location, last_modified, no_of_days) values (STR_TO_DATE($(date +%Y-%m-%d),'%Y-%m-%d'), $a, STR_TO_DATE($b, '%Y-%m-%d' )", $days);" -u root  '
```

Comment: On your second to last line, you have one opening `"` and two closing `"`.  Make your quotes consistent, and pair them up appropriately.

Comment: extra `"` : `STR_TO_DATE('$b', '%Y-%m-%d' )"`

Comment: are you aware that in shell script variable value will be treated as string if single quoted. I am seeing you are using `'` : `'$b'`. 
Check it out
`x=Haddop` : `echo "$x"` vs `echo '$x'`

Answer (score 1):

On your second to last line, you have one opening `"` and two closing `"`. Make your quotes consistent, and pair them up appropriately. – Paul L